# Text Editor Tags

Tags: pages, html, html-editor

Hello Wordpress StackExchange,

I'm embarrassed by what is probably a rookie question, but here it is:

I migrated and took over a website that a friend hired another developer to create, but I don't recognize these tags (main, article, equalizewrapper).  My question is, are they built into WordPress, or maybe are part of a customized theme?

I couldn't find any information in my Google searches for **equalizewrapper**.

Thanks in advance.

*Sample code below:*

```
[main]
[article]
  [equalizewrapper class="row full"]
    [equalize class="large-8 columns orange-bg contact-padding-1 right"]
      <h1 class="big-header">Contact %COMPANY%</h1>
      [contentinner class="large-12 columns strip-padding contact-form"]
<!-- Normal HTML / CSS was in here -->
      [/contentinner]
    [/equalize]
    [equalize class="large-4 columns contact-bg-1 left"]
      <span class="scroll-trigger side-accent-line inner"></span>
    [/equalize]
  [/equalizewrapper]
[/article]
[/main]
```

Comment: Code in brackets like this is usually called a Shortcode in WP. It could be coming from a theme, or from a plugin. I would suggest copying everything onto a staging or local site (and using a database migration plugin to handle the URL changes involved with that) so you can deactivate all the plugins and try a different theme, then turn the theme and plugins back on one by one until you isolate which one the shortcode is in. Or, if you can download all of the site's files, you could try searching for "register_shortcode" to find it.